# Bad ActivitySearchBinding, setContentView(binding.root) needed

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want this search class to search for users in a database, i put some functions i use most of the time into an abstract class called for instance "AbsBottom" that extends "AppCompactActivity"

I changed nothing other than the extended class, it works perfectly with the old class, however when i change it to the updated one it gives an error

This is the updated class

```
class SearchActivity : AbsBottom(R.layout.activity_search, R.id.bottomNav, R.id.search_nav) {

    private var user = mutableListOf(UserSearch()) 
        private var userAdapter = UserViewHolder()
        lateinit var binding: ActivitySearchBinding

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivitySearchBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            //setContentView(binding.root)
            //layout
            binding.recyclerProfile.setHasFixedSize(true)
            val llm = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            llm.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
            binding.recyclerProfile.layoutManager = llm
            
            //region Adapter Setup
            binding.recyclerProfile.adapter = userAdapter
            binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            //do stuff
                }

                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            //do other stuff
                }

            })
            //endregion
    }
}
```

This is the original

```
class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private var user = mutableListOf(UserSearch())
        private var userAdapter = UserViewHolder()
        lateinit var binding: ActivitySearchBinding

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivitySearchBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)

            bottomNavigation()
            //layout
            binding.recyclerProfile.setHasFixedSize(true)
            val llm = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            llm.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL

            binding.recyclerProfile.layoutManager = llm
            // userAdapter.setUsers(user)

            //region Adapter Setup
            binding.recyclerProfile.adapter = userAdapter
            binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            //do stuff
                }

                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            //do other stuff
                }

            })
            //endregion
    }
}
```

This is what the abstract class looks like

```
abstract class AbsBottom(val idC: Int, val idB: Int, val ac: Int) : AppCompatActivity() {
    protected lateinit var bottomNav : BottomNavigationView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(idC)
        bottomNav = findViewById(idB)
        bottomNav.selectedItemId = ac
    
    //etc
    }
}
```

The error doesn't say much, it says that it can't see the userAdapter, and as a result it doesn't load the list of searched users

Comment: Why did you extend **SearchActivity** as **Abs**? You just already created an abstract class named **AbsBottom** don't you understand that? there are two different types of **Names**. ``SearchActivity : Abs(R.layout.activity_search, R.id.bottomNav, R.id.search_nav)`` its need to be like this? ``SearchActivity : AbsBottom(R.layout.activity_search, R.id.bottomNav, R.id.search_nav)`` Am I right?

Comment: a typo my bad, however in the project the name is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, commenting the line

```
//setContentView(binding.root)
```

broke the binding.